# CSRF vulnerability - Rails 3.2.9

Tags: ruby, security, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I use rails 3.2.9 in webrick. My site seems to vulnerable to CSRF.
I have already added <%= csrf_meta_tags %> to the layout file..
And added the Protect_from_forgery in my application controller..

but when i try to make a Post request from a form in another domain, it's possible.. My site still seems to be vulnerable to CSRF..

I'm struck, wondering how to proceed! Pls help me out

Comment: do u have `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` in ur `application_controller`

Comment: @ashwintastic Hi, I'm using Rails 3.2.9 there is no support for the additional parameters like **protect_from_forgery with: :exception**

Comment: hey paste as it is inur application_controller
`protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token,
  if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format.json? }
`